# How to save output from ggforce::facet_grid_paginate in only one pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, pdf-generation, ggforce

I'm using the *ggforce* package to generate facetted plots over several pages:

```
library(ggforce) 

for(i in 1:6){
  ggplot(diamonds) +
    geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
    facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = i)

  ggsave(paste0("~/diamonds_", i, ".pdf"))
}
```

which is generating the expected 6 PDF files:
[image]

What is the easiest way have the output in **one single pdf** with 6 pages?

I understand this can be done with the `reports` and `pdftools` packages, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to accomplish this. I'd expect ggforce to provide the functionality for the output to be single-paged, but it looks like that's not the case?

Comment: What if you wrapped the for loop in a `pdf()/dev.off()` call?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't even need to use `ggsave` you can put all these plots into one `pdf` by:

```
pdf("~/diamonds_all.pdf")
for(i in 1:6){
  print(ggplot(diamonds) +
          geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
          facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = i))

}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Woah! I didn't know I could do that with `pdf()`, that's a simple and elegant solution. Thank you, @MikeH.
I believe you meant `ggsave` on your answer, BTW

Answer (score 12):

I'm facing a similar question and here's my solution, basically an extension of Mike H. answer.

Typically you want to plot all the pages and you don't know beforehand how many pages you have, also, you may want to print on standard A4 size paper. So:

```
library(ggforce) 

gg <- ggplot(diamonds) + 
    geom_point(aes(carat, price)) +
    facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = 1)
n <- n_pages(gg)

pdf('diamonds.pdf', paper= 'A4', w= 210/25.4, 297/25.4)
for(i in 1:n){
    print(gg + facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = i))
}
dev.off()
```

Code should be self-explanatory. The ugly thing is that you have to repeat `facet_wrap_paginate(...)` twice or wrap it into a dedicated function. I'd like to hear of a better solution...